# How to stop an infinite loop when you run Flask application in a production mode

Tags: python, flask, uwsgi

I have the Flask application. It has two buttons Start and Stop. A program should print 'pStart' (an infinite loop of pStart-s) when a user clicks Start and stop printing when a user clicks Stop. A user can resume printing when he clicks Start the second time.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import sys
flag1=True
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
  return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/start/')
def start():
  globals()['flag1']=True
  while flag1==True:
    print('pStart')
  return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/stop/')
def stop():
  globals()['flag1']=False
  return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Here is my templates\index.html

```
<!doctype html>


<head>
    <title>Test</title> 
    <meta charset=utf-8>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>My Website</h1>

<script type=text/javascript>
        $(function() {
          $('a#test').on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault()
            $.getJSON('/start',
                function(data) {
              //do nothing
            });
            document.getElementById('btn1').disabled = true;
            document.getElementById('btn2').disabled = false;
            return false;
          });
        });
</script>

<script type=text/javascript>
        $(function() {
          $('a#test1').on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault()
            $.getJSON('/stop',
                function(data) {
              //do nothing
            });
            document.getElementById('btn1').disabled = false;
            document.getElementById('btn2').disabled = true;
            return false;
          });
        });
</script>

<div class='container'>
        <form>
            <a href=# id=test><button id='btn1' class='btn btn-default'>Start</button></a>
        </form>
</div>  
<p>
<p>
<div class='container'>
        <form>
            <a href=# id=test1><button id='btn2' class='btn btn-default' type="button" disabled>Stop</button></a>
        </form>
</div>  
    </body>
```

This application works well in a development mode. However, when I run it with uWSGI I cannot stop it (stopless loop of print('pStart')).
Here is my wsgi.py

```
from myproject import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

uwsgi --socket 0.0.0.0:5000 --protocol=http -w wsgi:app

Update. The Flask application works if to use threads in code and enable threads "uwsgi --socket 0.0.0.0:5000 --protocol=http --enable-threads -w wsgi:app"

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import threading
import time
from werkzeug.serving import make_server
import signal

app = Flask(__name__)
threads = []
stop_flags = []

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/start/')
def start():
    stop_flags.append(False)
    thread = threading.Thread(target=run_loop, args=(len(stop_flags) - 1,))
    threads.append(thread)
    thread.start()
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/stop/')
def stop():
    stop_flags[-1] = True
    return render_template('index.html')

def run_loop(thread_id):
    while not stop_flags[thread_id]:
        print('pStart')
        time.sleep(0.5)

def signal_handler(signum, frame):
    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()
    server.shutdown()
    sys.exit(0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, signal_handler)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
    server = make_server('0.0.0.0', 5000, app)
    server.serve_forever()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The while loop in the `start` function runs indefinitely and can not handle incoming requests. So when you run the application in production mode, the server is not able to handle any incoming requests after the `start` function is called !

You can use a background task to run the `print('pStart')` continuously while allowing the Flask application to handle incoming requests, to do so use the threading modules.

Here's how you can create the func in the background with threading :

```
  from flask import Flask, render_template
import threading
import time

app = Flask(__name__)
threads = []
stop_flags = []

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/start/')
def start():
    stop_flags.append(False)
    thread = threading.Thread(target=run_loop, args=(len(stop_flags) - 1,))
    threads.append(thread)
    thread.start()
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/stop/')
def stop():
    stop_flags[-1] = True
    return render_template('index.html')

def run_loop(thread_id):
    while not stop_flags[thread_id]:
        print('pStart')
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: How to stop this thread? I would like to be able to pause/resume printing. Could you post a whole code?

Comment: I just edited the code i wrote a full example with start and stop functions ! :)

Comment: I made tests. It works in a development mode, however, I cannot resume Thread when I click Start the second time (RuntimeError: threads can only be started once). When I run this code in a production mode the program prints only 7 pStart-s, then I press Ctrl-C and it prints endless loop of pStart-s which I cannot stop by pressing Stop button.

Comment: To solve this issue, you can create a new thread each time the Start button is clicked. i tried to edit the code another time hope this will work for you !